# Where can I find the file where a specific topic was created?

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can see the available topics using `rostopic list`. However, I would like to see the files (the source code) where they are being published from (or where they have been created). Is this possible somehow?  When I execute the comand `rostopic list` I see certain topics which I can't find anywhere inside the ROS package which is supposed to have created them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317318/where-can-i-find-the-file-where-a-specific-topic-was-created?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2019-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I would like to see the files (the source code) where they are being published from (or where they have been created). Is this possible somehow?

In general (and with "a single command")? No, I would say you can't. Not with any of the command line tools that are provided "as part of a standard ROS install".

If however you know which nodes are publishing or subscribing to those topics (note: topics are not "created", in fact, in some sense they do not really even "exist"), you could:

1. figure out the package that hosts the/those node(s)
2. retrieve the source code of the package
3. use something like `grep` to find occurences of the topic name in the code

But note though: due to remapping and dynamic topic name creation, there is no guarantee at all that you will be able to find the publishers this way. Especially with Python nodes, as Python is so flexible that many "crazy" things can be done at runtime making this sort of sleuthing rather difficult.

> I see certain topics which I can't find anywhere inside the ROS package which is supposed to have created them.

nitpick: nodes can be publishers. Packages can't.

Also note that `rostopic list` shows you a topic name in three cases:

1. topic is published to
2. topic is subscribed to
3. topic is both published *and* subscribed to

So it could be that a subscriber causes a topic to appear in `rostopic list`, and that subscriber could be "anywhere".

---

Edit:

> I'm trying to use [this ROS package](https://github.com/romarcg/pioneer3at_simulation). After having launched the Pioneer 3AT, if I type `rostopic list`, I see a bunch of topics related to the Pioneer, but I can't find the place where they are being published from.

Looking at the repository you linked, two things stand out:

1. this is not a package, but an entire *workspace* with one package (`pioneer3at_simulation`) and two git submodules pointing to other repositories (with even more packages)
2. the main package `pioneer3at_simulation` provides a collection of `.launch` files ([here](https://github.com/romarcg/pioneer3at_simulation/tree/d763bfcba95e773b9a0ac5f97d8f03f072fd3a51/catkin_ws_src/pioneer3at_simulation/launch)) that together start (among other things): `gazebo` and something called `teleop_joy`.

Gazebo then is configured to load various `.world` files, `urdf_spawner` is then used to inject a model of a 3-AT, that loads multiple Gazebo plugins, etc, etc. I haven't checked the two repositories linked in via the git submodules, but I expect those to also either provide additional nodes and/or plugins.

Gazebo, the teleop nodes *and* all of the Gazebo plugins will both publish and subscribe to topics, and those will appear in `rostopic list`.

So in order to find "the file where a specific topic was created", you'd have to check the sources of all those packages.

---

Edit2: I haven't checked, but there is a small chance that you could actually figure out where a topic is published or subscribed to without `grep`ping through source code: the ROS log(s). It might be possible to print out the source line nr (when configured using [ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Console_Output_Formatting)) and a sufficiently high logging level (`DEBUG` or even higher). If this works, I wouldn't recommend doing this in production systems though.

---

Edit 3:

> For example, using `rostopic list`, I see the topic `/pioneer3at/camera_down/image_raw`. The only place inside that package where I find that topic is in the file [`rqt_gui_cameras.perspective`](https://github.com/romarcg/pioneer3at_simulation/tree/master/catkin_ws_src/pioneer3at_simulation/config)

This is a good example of what I described in my original answer ("dynamic topic name creation"): that topic name is not something you will find directly in the sources of any of those packages, as it's dynamically created inside a xacro macro ([here](https://github.com/romarcg/pioneer3at_simulation/blob/d763bfcba95e773b9a0ac5f97d8f03f072fd3a51/catkin_ws_src/pioneer3at_simulation/urdf/pioneer3at.urdf.xacro#L373)) that loads a Gazebo camera plugin ([here](https://github.com/romarcg/pioneer3at_simulation/blob/d763bfcba95e773b9a0ac5f97d8f03f072fd3a51/catkin_ws_src/pioneer3at_simulation/urdf/pioneer3at.urdf.xacro#L406-L443)) which finally is instantiated [here](https://github.com/romarcg/pioneer3at_simulation/blob/d763bfcba95e773b9a0ac5f97d8f03f072fd3a51/catkin_ws_src/pioneer3at_simulation/urdf/pioneer3at.urdf.xacro#L564) with the argument `"down"`.

Taking all that together we end up with a Gazebo `sensor` that uses a Gazebo ROS Camera plugin, has the name `camera_down` and publishes on the topic `/pioneer3at/camera_down/image_raw` (as you can see [here](https://github.com/romarcg/pioneer3at_simulation/blob/d763bfcba95e773b9a0ac5f97d8f03f072fd3a51/catkin_ws_src/pioneer3at_simulation/urdf/pioneer3at.urdf.xacro#L432-L433)).

The complete string `/pioneer3at/camera_down/image_raw` doesn't appear in any of these sources, but if we take the dynamic behaviour of all the involved components into account we can figure it out.

Note that in this particular case `grep`ping the output of `xacro` after converting the `pioneer3at.urdf.xacro` file with the proper arguments supplied would have resulted in at least parts of the topic name appearing in the `.urdf` file.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-03-03**:
I even tried to use `grep` to find the topics, but I didn't find them. Anyway, yes, I was aware of the fact that you can't create topics (but I used the term "create" not to use both publish and subscribe). I also know that topics are published by nodes, but nodes reside inside packages.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-03**:\

> I even tried to use `grep` to find the topics, but I didn't find them

If you can give an example of a topic you couldn't find, perhaps I can try to see/explain why that could have been the case.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-03**:\

> I also know that topics are published by nodes, but nodes reside inside packages.

True, but: I live in a house, and I make bread sometimes. My house doesn't make bread, I do.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-03-03**:
I'm trying to use [this ROS package](https://github.com/romarcg/pioneer3at_simulation). After having launched the Pioneer 3AT, if I type `rostopic list`, I see a bunch of topics related to the Pioneer, but I can't find the place where they are being published from.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-03-03**:
Yes, but I am referring to the package inside the workspace `pioneer3at_simulation`. I only used this package.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-03**:
I believe my answer still applies. That pkg contains a nr of launch files that start all sorts of nodes, from a nr of other packages.

If you can give an example of a topic name that you can't find (as I asked earlier), perhaps that could be explained.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-03-03**:
For example, using `rostopic list`, I see the topic `/pioneer3at/camera_down/image_raw`. The only place inside that package where I find that topic is in the file [`rqt_gui_cameras.perspective`](https://github.com/romarcg/pioneer3at_simulation/tree/master/catkin_ws_src/pioneer3at_simulation/config)